# How to merge the header with main page in Django template where both are getting data from different querysets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a situation where I want to create search in my page. I want to create search without it mixing with the original page as I need to use this same search in more than one page. I created search table in a div in templates folder and named it MySearch.html. Now, I have included that in the main page as {% include 'MySearch.html'%} and it is able to give me the drop down with static text but not with the options that I am filling with query set.

In urls.py -

```
url(r'Search', myproj.type4.views.ShowSearch, name='Search'),
```

In ShowSearch() -

```
def ShowSearch(request):
        countryqueryset = Type4Main.objects.all().values('country').distinct()
        return render(request,'MySearch.html',{
                'countryqueryset':countryqueryset,
        })
```

In MySearch.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title> My Search
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id ="mysearch" name="mysearch">
            <table id="mysearchtbl" name="mysearchtbl">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Country
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="country">
                            <option value="0">Select</option>
                                {% for country in countryqueryset %}
                                    <option value="{{country.country}}">{{country.country}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

I can only see Select as option when it is merging with the main page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Views render templates, not the other way round: templates don't call views. If you are not viewing the page via the ShowSearch URL then the data from that view won't be passed to the template.

For data that needs to be included on every page regardless of the view, use a custom template tag.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. Thanks for the suggest ion :) (y)